# Custom endpoint to get all custom taxonomy terms

Tags: rest-api, json, endpoints

I'm trying to build a custom endpoint to get all terms from custom taxonomy

the taxonomy name is `cats`

I'm using this code

```
   function wl_cats() {
        $args = [
            'numberposts' => 99999,
            'taxonomy' => 'cats'
        ];
        $cats = get_terms('cats');
        $data = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
            $data[$i]['id'] = $cat->ID;
            $data[$i]['title'] = $cat->the_title();
            $i++;
        }
        return $data;
    }
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'cats', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wl_cats',
    ]);

});
```

Is their any way better than that? because I got data `null`

Comment: If your taxonomy has `show_in_rest` get to `true`, there will already be an endpoint for this.